# Suggested edits review history should show results

Tags: feature-request, review

Currently, the edit review queue history shows whether *you* voted to Approve or Reject (or Improve, I assume) a given edit, but you have to click on it to see whether or not the edit was Approved or Rejected overall.

It would be good to indicate in some way the final result of the edit along with your vote.  This could take the form of another column, color coding of your vote, or just an icon when your vote matched the final results.

This would be good for new reviewers (such as myself) to be able to look at the ones where we "got it wrong" to see other people's reasoning.  I'm sure experienced reviewers could find a use for that information as well - spotting "serial approvers", maybe?

Comment: There is a [meta-tag:feature-request] laying around which is related to this (show statistics as to how many of your votes were agreed upon my others).

Comment: @Matt - I'm not surprised.  I had assumed that there would already be a request for it, but I couldn't find it while searching.  Can you link it?

Comment: `@`Bobson: I'm not saying it's a duplicate, I'm just saying that there are a variety of *related* suggestions out there (including this one) to get some form of this functionality added (*all of which I'm fully behind*).

Comment: @Matt - Ah, I misunderstood.  I definitely did see a bunch of related changes.